# Java Printf - N places of decimals

Tags: java, printf, decimal

I want to format my decimal number output, so that it has N amount of decimal space.

For certain amount of places I know you can just do

```
System.out.printf("%.2f",number);
```

but I want to do something like

```
System.out.printf("%.(%d)f",spaces,number);
```

So basically the same output but the number of decimal space changes based on the input (the user determines amount of decimal space).
I understand that line doesn't work but I don't know other ways to do this.

Comment: Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38122245/522444)

Comment: Why not just take the user input as an int like `int numberOfDecimalPlaces = scanner.nextInt();` and then just do `System.out.printf("%." + numberOfDecimalPlaces  + "f",number);`

Comment: Note that what @OHGODSPIDERS is showing you is what is shown in the answer in my link above.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

- `%` escapes `%` so `%%` formats a single `%`.
- `formatted` does the same thing as `String.format()`
- After `formatted` is done, the format string will be `%.2f%n`

```
int n = 2;
double value = 3.88833; 

System.out.printf("%%.%df%n".formatted(n), value);
```

prints

```
3.89
```